# javascript redirect to url after random time

Tags: javascript, redirect, random

I have this javascript redirect script which works

```js
<p>You will be redirected in <span id="counter">120</span> second(s).</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
        location.href = 'http://example.com';
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
</script>
```

My question is: How can I get a random number (e.g. between 60 and 120) instead of a fixed number before the script redirects?

Comment: Did you try using the javascript random function Math.floor((Math.random() * 120) + 1) and add it to the $('#counter').html(here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1, you basically have to multiply the result by the length of your interval - this will give you offset, which you then add to the beginning of the interval. The code will look like this:

```
var min = 60; 
var max = 120; 
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

Comment: Could you show me how the complete code would look like - incl. the <p>-tags?

Comment: there are probably nicer ways:  
<p>You will be redirected in <span id="counter"></span> second(s).</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var min = 60; 
var max = 120; 
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
var i = document.getElementById('counter');
i.innerHTML = rnd;

function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(rnd)<=0) {
        location.href = 'http://example.com';
    }
 rnd = rnd - 1;
    i.innerHTML = rnd;
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
</script>